# How to center text in a custom segment controller? Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol, text-alignment

I am making a custom segment controller. I faced into the following problem: the text inside the selectable view is not centered. I would like to find a universal solution so that the text remains in the center of the selected segment, regardless of the number of cells. Please , hellp. Thanks a lot!

Image: [Example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC4dk.png)

Code:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomSegmentedCntrl: UIControl {
    private var buttons = [UIButton]()
    private var selector: UIView!
    var selectedSegmentIndex = 0
   
    private var segments = [String]() {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var textColor: UIColor = .clear  {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var selectorColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var selectorTextColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }
    
    func configure(with segmentButtons:[String]) {
        self.segments = segmentButtons
    }
    
    
    func setProperties(borderWidth: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, selectorColor: UIColor, selectorTextColor: UIColor) {
        self.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.borderColor = borderColor
        self.selectorColor = selectorColor
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.selectorTextColor = selectorTextColor
    }
    
    
    
    func updateView() {
        buttons.removeAll()
        subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview()}
        
        let buttonTitles = segments
        
        for buttonTitle in buttonTitles {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            buttons.append(button)
        }
        
        let selectorWidth = frame.width / CGFloat(buttonTitles.count)
        selector = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: selectorWidth, height: frame.height))
        selector.layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
        selector.backgroundColor = selectorColor
        addSubview(selector)
        
        ///Stack view constraints
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        for (buttonIndex, btn) in buttons.enumerated() {
            btn.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
            
            if btn == button {
                print(buttonIndex)
                selectedSegmentIndex = buttonIndex
                let selectorStartPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttons.count) * CGFloat(buttonIndex)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    self.selector.frame.origin.x = selectorStartPosition
                })
                btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

ViewController is look like this:

```
  //View at the storyboard
 @IBOutlet weak var secondSegmentedControll: CustomSegmentedCntrl!

   func installSecondCell() {
       self.secondSegmentedControll.borderColor = .green
       self.secondSegmentedControll.selectorTextColor = .blue
       self.secondSegmentedControll.selectorColor = .red
       self.secondSegmentedControll.configure(with: ["one", "two", "three", "four"])
       self.secondSegmentedControll.borderWidth = 1
   }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       installSecondCell()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Add this:  `stackView.distribution = .fillEqually` to updateView()